# What technologies are used to develop games for tablets and iPhones?

Tags: iphone, flash, html5

1. What technologies are used to develop games for tablets and iPhones?
2. Would Flash be commonly used?
3. Is HTML5 capable of animation and interactivity, or would a game file simply be placed within HTML5 code?
4. Is Flash and HTML5, and then wrapping the game for different phone/tablet operating systems a common combination?

Comment: This is quite broad range of things you are asking. Point 3. specifically, which is solely about HTML5 and therefore quite out of scope of the rest of the question, maybe you could move it to a separate question? For the rest of the question it would help to be more specific, e.g. are you asking about iOS devices only, or are you also interested in other platforms, such as Android or Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. C/C++ and/or Objective-C are used to develop games for iOS (iPad/iPhone). Java or C++ (using NDK) is used to develop for Android. Usually OpenGL ES is being used for rendering on these devices. There are engines like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), [Shiva](http://www.stonetrip.com/) or [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) that allow publishing to different devices. These engines usually come with an own editor and you program in C#, Lua or Javascript.
2. Flash isn't very common (at least when it comes to games) because of performance concerns.
3. Technically yes, but the tools and frameworks for HTML5 development are currently not on the same level as something like Unity. Also the different devices have different browsers which may require browser-specific workarounds. The performance is also heavily dependent on the JavaScript engine that's being used. You won't be able to achieve the same performance as with a native app (if that matters for your game).
4. No, because Flash content doesn't run on iOS and Adobe discontinued development of their mobile flash player. With Adobe Flash CS5.5 or Flex Builder 4.5 you can export your AIR app as native app for iOS, Android or Blackberry though.

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices such as iPhones and iPads don't support Flash at all. There are a few HTML5-based games, s HTML5 is capable of animation and interactivity. You might want to look at OpenGL.

There's a great book called [iPhone Game Projects](http://www.amazon.co.uk/iPhone-Games-Projects-Books-Professionals/dp/1430219688), and another great book (for Android-based devices) called [Pro Android Games](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1430226471/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=swanseastud0e-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=1430226471).

Comment: Projects developed in Flash (namely, Adobe AIR) can be put on iOS devices as native apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use of flash is good but the old concept. You can use HTML5 which is latest technology coming in mobile game development you should start. It is very much user-friendly and capable with animation and interactivity.

Comment: This question is off topic; please avoid answering them. Flag them as such instead :)